# SSH logging Dreamhost

Tags: linux, ssh, dreamhost

How can I log all attempts to ssh onto my Dreamhost server? Or if the log already exists where is it?  I checked logs/example.com/html/ I cannot find any log file for the ssh logins.

I want to see when all failed attempts or successful attempts to SSH in my server happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Dreamhost (and other hosts/servers that have not explicitly disabled the "last" command), you can get a list of all recent login attempts using:

```
last -i | grep <youruser>
last -if /var/log/wtmp.1 | grep <youruser>
```

The first command will give you your login history for the current month, while the second will give you your login history for the prior month.

---

See the Dreamhost Wiki for more: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Troubleshooting_Hacked_Sites

Comment: I'm sorry, the last command will not log unsuccessful login attempts, only successful ones. Hope it's useful nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Call support to get you the logs, as those ssh logs are not exposed in the logs folder they show you thru SSH (unless you have a VPS account). Nevertheless, they keep them ALL.

Comment: If you log in to your panel and get into support section, you can request assistance. If you write them, there's no charge (afaik, I worked on a big account with unlimited subdomains/DBs), but if you call there's some extra fee per request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are under Ubuntu/Debian Linux, you can get this logs here:

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: That is good if I had root access on Dreamhost servers. Alas I do not.